# Two stack in assembly

Tags: assembly, graphics, x86, stack

I am tring to do a game in assembly(something simple, not to  complicated kind of snake) and I need two stacks for that. I will be glad if you could show me how to create and use two stacks.
Just for knowledge, I need the stacks to check if the snake cut itself and also to paint the snake's body.

Comment: There can only be one call stack unless you're multi-treading. The rest must be user stacks (that is, managed manually). The algorithm isn't too difficult.

Comment: Could you explain why you need a stack for checking if the snake intersects itself? If you represent the playing field as a 2D array you could easily detect that by checking if a segment of the snake would end up in the same cell where another segment already is located.

Comment: @TJR check my answer . see if it can be helpfull

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.create snake array . and shift them . and add head `snake[0] (x;y ofhead)` then clear `snake[snake_size]` which is tail .
If it be with map you can flag snake body on that maps[x,y] area and draw whole map looping throw it using map values
pseudo code:

```
map[x,y]=1 //snake body 
map[x,y]=0 //nothing 
map[x,y]=2 //fruit
map[x,y]=-1 //fench
```

for  moving snake  here is simple code: (shifting snake array to right):

(note: our snake array elements Word(2bytes) .  so writing `snake[x]` actually  should point to `snake[x*2]` address ;

```
      mov   cx, snake_size
      ; di=snake_size*2
      mov   di, snake_size    
      add di,di   ;// di=di*2
    move_array:
      ;  snake[x]=snake[x-1];
      mov   ax, snake[di-2] ;  
      mov   snake[di], ax 
      ;  --x (x=x-1)
      sub   di, 2  
      loop  move_array

//c style loop code will be 
for(int i=snake_size;i>0;i--){
   snake[i]=snake[i-1];
}
```

after this movement add new position of head `snake[0]` and clear `tail=snake[snake_size]`  and flag those on the map ,too :
[image]

for seeing if he eats fruit you should check head position with map[head.x,head.y] ==2 or for fench you check with -1

for seeing if he cut or not . you should loop throw entire body and see if head collision with body

**And Coming to stack** :

- it is array with Filo behaviour .
- you need store index .
- add value to that mem[index] and increase index when pushing `;mem[index]=value;++index;`
- and when popping decrease index and return mem[index]   `;--index;return mem[index]`

Comment: If you mean doing an array to the snake - how will you change its size.  If not, how do you know were the tail(after deleting the tail you need to find the new position of it on the map). And by the way, the map is an array?

Comment: @TJR for snake we got snake_array with capacity  of the maximum length of snake .think this length will never exceed (mapx*mapy)/2 . we got s_size that holds current snake size. if we increment s_size then snake size will be changed .cause we clear snake[s_size]  which is tail . .map is twodimensional array .we use map for cheking and displaying purpose . also check my answer . i improved formatting and  made things more clear